# Attached image no longer available

Tags: support, status-reproduced

In [one of my answers](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5230/5232#5232), imgur.com apparently scraped one of the attached pictures (at least the link now displays "The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available." placeholder).

The image should be here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gost

[image: missing?]

This is a bit unfortunate, since it is used as an official image upload around here. Is it just some kind of once-every-20-years glitch, or are all our uploaded images going to vanish one day?

Comment: Just to note...the photos, which appear to be some kind of green stuffed animal, currently show up for me. I also checked the direct URL's for each image, and they all seem to work as well. Maybe it is some kind of distributed caching glitch in imgur.com that can be corrected?

Comment: @jrista: It's still missing for me, so it indeed looks more like caching issue. I'm glad my stuffed animal pic isn't lost forever :-)

Comment: Hmmm. It's also missing for me. The second and third images work, but I get the same "does not exist" for the first. And I tried from three different locations (although all of them on the east coast of the US).

Comment: All images uploaded to to places like imageshack and others (I'm not familiar with imgur) will expire eventually.
As this is a site which is highly dependant on images (compared to stackoverflow) it could be a big issue if images start to vanish everywhere. Is there the possibility of incorporating some sort of photo.stackexchange upload feature? I realise this might have rights implications but still

Comment: @ChristFletcher: imgur.com *is* the photo.se upload feature, that's why I'm whining here :-) Anyway, the photo is visible again, so it probably was just some kind of caching glitch.

Comment: Ah, the wonder of distributed caching.

Comment: I don't know, the first is missing for me and I haven't looked at this question for a long time so that does not look like a caching issue to me.

Comment: Still isn't showing up for me. Is it really working for all the admins?

Comment: Gone again for me. (Not an admin, though.)

Comment: I have the same issue now.

Comment: I used to have the same issue, but now it seems to work ok.

Answer (score 3):

we have a network-wide imgur pro account, per

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

This means images will be available forever. However, **images *must* be uploaded through our editor for this to work.**

We renamed all imgur images uploaded since that blog post to reflect our custom domain at imgur,

`i.stack.imgur.com`

There were a few blips with this initially (and there is still a corner case for users who manually uploaded things to imgur) but in general it should be working now.